# Directed Graph using networkD3 and a data frame

Tags: r, data-visualization, networkd3

I have included a data frame which depicts a very small subset of the data I am using. My aim is to construct an interactive network due to the large number of nodes in the data.

```
library(networkD3)    
screenName <- c("ZV8Lxypirmo2T8z", "Zwoodbutcher", "zX3GZYH7Ea5FKhx", "zXZK7fkzrpPpJdb", 
                "ZyaTheKing", "zzzcccbbbmmm")    
mention <- c("GianCavallotto:", "IanPTrait:", "JahovasWitniss:", "Veachtravis:", 
             "visecs:", "Charles_HRH:")    
n <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)   
data <- data.frame(screenName,mention,n)    
simpleNetwork(data)
```

The above code allows for the construction of an interactive undirected network graph. I came across the `forceNetwork()` function under the `networkD3`R library which might help here. But I do not really know how to convert the data.frame for its usage in this function. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Take a look at ggraph package and the function, `graph_from_data_frame()`

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for help with. You simply give it the list of nodes, links and parameters needed and it graphs seamlessly. Check here to see if the explanation and example helps...  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkD3/networkD3.pdf

Comment: @bethanyP There  are parameters called `Nodes`,`NodeID` and `Group` in the `forceNetwork()` function. What values should I pass to these parameters?

Comment: @Simon Jackson  I tried using the `ggraph` package too. With the data I have, it becomes too overcrowded even with `repel` set as `TRUE`.

Comment: @adhok in that case, I'd say you'd need a different plot you're, or to filter certain connections or nodes out before coveritng to graph object.

Comment: Both `simpleNetwork` & `forceNetwork` will create a force directed graph. In order to get the kind of graph you are looking for out of `forceNetwork`, you need more data fields. You do not have enough information about the graph objects. You need to have nodes with ID's, and designate source nodes for the interaction that are the start and target nodes that are the recipient, you need Values for links (also called edges) that communicate the relationship intensity in a force graph. You have three fields with unclear identities..that needs to be resolved.

Comment: @adhok sorry, I meant igraph package (can't seem to edit my other comment via mobile app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions `simpleNetwork()` and `forceNetwork()` are designed to work differently.

`simpleNetwork()` takes one data frame as its primary input, and by default assumes that the first column is the 'source' of each link and the that the second column is the 'target' of each link. It does not require a data frame describing nodes because it assumes the only nodes are those that are linked to something in the link data frame and creates the node list internally by determining the unique values in the links data frame.

`forceNetwork()` is more powerful and flexible, but it requires you to pass two data frames, one for links and one for nodes. You pass to the parameter `Nodes` a data frame that contains a list of unique nodes. The parameters `NodeID` and `Group` are character values that define the name of the column in the nodes data frame that contains that information, e.g. `NodeID = 'name'` and `Group = 'type'`. The `Group` column in the nodes data frame is used to define the color of the nodes, and is not really necessary, but `forceNetwork()` requires it, so you can just make a column in the nodes data frame that has the same value for every row, e.g. `1`.

You can take the code you have above, and build the necessary data frames to use `forceNetwork()` like this (for instance)...

```
library(networkD3)
screenName <- c("ZV8Lxypirmo2T8z", "Zwoodbutcher", "zX3GZYH7Ea5FKhx", 
                "zXZK7fkzrpPpJdb", "ZyaTheKing", "zzzcccbbbmmm")
mention <- c("GianCavallotto:", "IanPTrait:", "JahovasWitniss:", "Veachtravis:", 
             "visecs:", "Charles_HRH:")
n <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)

nodeFactors <- factor(sort(unique(c(screenName, mention))))
nodes <- data.frame(name = nodeFactors, group = 1)

screenName <- match(screenName, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1
mention <- match(mention, levels(nodeFactors)) - 1
links <- data.frame(screenName, mention, n)

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = 'screenName', 
             Target = 'mention', Value = 'n', NodeID = 'name', Group = 'group')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain with the example from the documentation.

You'd need two dataframes - `links` and `nodes`.

```
data(MisLinks)
glimpse(MisLinks)
#Observations: 254
#Variables: 3
#$ source <int> 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 1...
#$ target <int> 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 2, 0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 16, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18, ...
#$ value  <int> 1, 8, 10, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4...

length(unique(c(MisLinks$source,MisLinks$target)))
#[1] 77

data(MisNodes)
glimpse(MisNodes)
#Observations: 77
#Variables: 3
#$ name  <fctr> Myriel, Napoleon, Mlle.Baptistine, Mme.Magloire, CountessdeLo, Geborand, Champterci...
#$ group <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, ...
#$ size  <int> 15, 20, 23, 30, 11, 9, 11, 30, 8, 29, 29, 9, 18, 12, 16, 22, 21, 11, 19, 10, 8, 13, ...
```

Each entry in the `source` and `target` of the `links` dataframe is a node (integers 0,1,...,n). In this case there are 77 unique nodes. So you'd need a `nodes` dataframe with 77 nodes describing the node attributes. The first entry in `nodes` dataframe is node `0`, the next entry is node `1` and so on. The `nodes` dataframe must be sorted according to this sequence. This is the only way to tie the `nodes` dataframe to the `links` dataframe.

```
# Create graph
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Target = "target", Value = "value", 
             Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", 
             opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE)
```